# How to use EditTexts and Checkboxes on a Listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

**EDIT:** I'm Still stuck in this Problem so i figured out and i need to, every time that i add a new item to the list, i need to read the status of the CheckBoxes and EditTexts and save them somewhere, then i have to use the data and add a new item, and finally put them one more time on the ListView, so, i don't know what is the right way to go over the ListView to get those states. Someone can help me with that? Bellow is the question that i have posted before.

I'm working on a app for my restaurant, and for the orders i have a list view with two checkboxes, one EditText and a Textview, so i have an

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

That has a list of dishes the client order, so, if i have some text in my EditText if i add new items to the list it erases it, i know i have to save the data but i dont know how, same with checkboxes, the state loses if i add a new item to the list.

This the code:
The variables:

```
HashMap<String,String> comandas = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

And this is what i have to add the items to the listview

```
  private void mostrarOrden3(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            //El cont se utiliza para que el primer elemento de la lista sea el mas nuevo
            int cont =result.length();
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){

                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(cont-1);
                String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID_PLATOS);
                String nombre = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NOMBRE_PLATOS);
                String precio = jo.getString(Config.TAG_PRECIO_PLATOS);
                String descripcion = jo.getString(Config.TAG_DESCRIPCION_PLATOS);
                String nombrecategoria = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NOMBRECATEGORIA_PLATOS);







                comandas = new HashMap<>();
                comandas.put(Config.TAG_ID_PLATOS,id);
                comandas.put(Config.TAG_NOMBRE_PLATOS,nombre);
                comandas.put(Config.TAG_PRECIO_PLATOS,precio);
                comandas.put(Config.TAG_DESCRIPCION_PLATOS,descripcion);
                comandas.put(Config.TAG_NOMBRECATEGORIA_PLATOS,nombrecategoria);



                System.out.println(nombre);

                list.add(comandas);
                cont--;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

                NuevaOrdenActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item_platos,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_NOMBRE_PLATOS},
                new int[]{ R.id.name});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

I need to save those items whit his states when the adapter is refreshed put again on it an continuing adding items.
What is the correct way to do that?
And i have another issue im using a SwiperRefreshLayout on the ListView and when im scrolling on it the text on the EditText duplicates on the lis below, im from Guatemala so my examples are in Spanish, but in the example apears two items to have the number 7 and i have only added one.
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLqpR.png)
[Example 2 whit the other number 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0DBc.png)

I would thank you so much for helping me whit this proyect. Have a nice day!

Comment: Have you researched "view recycling" in ListViews? Your data is cached as the rows leave and enter the screen. You need a "ViewHolder pattern"

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes i was searching and find that here in stack, but at least the examples that i found was from How to put them back with the ViewHolder, and i don't know how to save the state first, but, y keep searching with this new keywords :)